# Find column with the highest value (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns that range from 0 to 100. I would like to add a column on to the dataframe that contains the name of the column from among these that has the greatest value for each row. So:

```
one   two   three four  COLUMN_I_WANT_TO_CREATE
5     40    12    19    two
90    15    58    23    one
74    95    34    12    two
44    81    22    97    four
10    59    59    44    [either two or three, selected randomly]
```

etc.

Bonus points if the solution can resolve ties randomly.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with parameter `axis=1`:

```
print df
   one  two  three  four
0    5   40     12    19
1   90   15     58    23
2   74   95     34    12
3   44   81     22    97

df['COLUMN_I_WANT_TO_CREATE'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print df
   one  two  three  four COLUMN_I_WANT_TO_CREATE
0    5   40     12    19                     two
1   90   15     58    23                     one
2   74   95     34    12                     two
3   44   81     22    97                    four
```

With random duplicity max values is it more complicated.

You can first find all [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) values by `x[(x == x.max())]`. Then you need `index` values, where apply [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html). But it works only with `Series`, so `index` is converted to
`Series` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html). Last you can select only first value of `Serie` by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print df
   one  two  three  four
0    5   40     12    19
1   90   15     58    23
2   74   95     34    12
3   44   81     22    97
4   10   59     59    44
5   59   59     59    59
6   10   59     59    59
7   59   59     59    59
```

```
#first run
df['COL']=df.apply(lambda x:x[(x==x.max())].index.to_series().sample(frac=1).iloc[0], axis=1)
print df
   one  two  three  four    COL
0    5   40     12    19    two
1   90   15     58    23    one
2   74   95     34    12    two
3   44   81     22    97   four
4   10   59     59    44  three
5   59   59     59    59    one
6   10   59     59    59    two
7   59   59     59    59  three

#one of next run
df['COL']=df.apply(lambda x:x[(x==x.max())].index.to_series().sample(frac=1).iloc[0], axis=1)
print df
   one  two  three  four    COL
0    5   40     12    19    two
1   90   15     58    23    one
2   74   95     34    12    two
3   44   81     22    97   four
4   10   59     59    44    two
5   59   59     59    59    one
6   10   59     59    59  three
7   59   59     59    59   four
```

Comment: Is `sample` doing the randomization? I don't quite see how it does that.

Comment: Yes, please check link.

Comment: Ah—that's not quite what I meant by resolving ties randomly. (I've updated my question to clarify.)

Comment: @jezrael: this isn't the kind of sampling the OP wants.  He wants to randomize *among the maxima per row*, not *among the maxima column*.